# Metal Gear Solid 5: The Phantom Pain Strange Circle

Tags: pc, metal-gear-solid-5-the-phantom-pain, windows-10

When I run the game, I have this strange blue circle on the game. Can anybody tell me why I am getting that?

I was thinking maybe because my screen is touch enabled. I used external monitor, it did not fix the problem. 
I could not find any options in the game to turn it off.

I don't know why, but apparently no one has reported such a problem on internet.
I changed the resolution of the game, no matter what, I will have the blue circle on the right of the screen.

I am using Alienware 13 R3.

[image]

Comment: If you disable your touchscreen, do you still get the issue (even if you're displaying the game on another monitor)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. I just tried that, no change. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Is it only the title screen or in game as well? If it's just the title screen, I wouldn't really care. I would be curious though.

Comment: it is there in all parts of the game. Regardless where I am.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like part of the "Nahimic Sound Tracker" software that comes with some MSI graphic cards. You can find more information about it [here](https://nahimic.helprace.com/i39-how-do-i-disable-the-sound-tracker). According to the official site,

> You can disable the Sound Tracker by switching OFF the button on the
>   bottom left of its page. In game, you can also use the hotkey CTRL +
>   SHIFT + S to turn OFF or ON the Sound Tracker.